# If a character returns early from night scavenging, is that character better rested?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

When characters are out scavenging at night, one can usually send them home early.  Which makes sense, once the characters' packs are full and you've obtained any accessible desired items.

On the other hand staying longer would allow one to work on some of the more time-consuming scavenging tasks, like clearing rubble by hand.

That leads me to the inquiry:  Does a character receive a rest bonus or otherwise for returning early from night scavenging?

The characters appear to arrive home at the beginning of the day, so it might be that no advantage other than safety is gained.
<sub>A related question:  Can a returning character help the characters at home repel invaders?  Edit: Answer **It does not appear so.**</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unfortunately, no.

**The moment you go scavenging, it counts as "stayed awake that night"**. Even if you just pick up a pile you left the night before, and are back before 10 PM. So you cannot sleep or guard that night.